# Pyserial not reading serial input correctly and raising error

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am working on a code which reads serial input from arduino, using pyserial. The input string is supposedly something like "2786,7,258.00,10,20,5,0,2000,4809.14,N,1131.70,E" But what pyserial is giving is "286,9,246.00,10,20,,0,2000,4809.74,N,131.90,E" Also after few seconds the program is raising an error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/saurabh/Desktop/testreception.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
    File "/home/saurabh/Desktop/testreception.py", line 9, in main
      x.append(ser.readline())
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 460,  in read
    raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)')
`SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)
```

My code:

```
import serial

def main():
    a = 1
    x = []
    i = 0
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
    while(a):
        x.append(ser.readline())
        print(x[i])
        i = i+1

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The arduino Code is:

```
 int TEAM_ID = 2786;
 int h = 00;
 int m = 00;
 int s = 00;
 int MISSION_TIME = s*1 + m*100 + h*10000;
 float ALT_SENSOR = 300;
 int OUTSIDE_TEMP = 10;
 int INSIDE_TEMP = 20;
 int VOLTAGE = 12;
 int FSW_STATE = 0;
 int ROTOR_RATE = 2000;
 float LATTITUDE = 4807.038;
 char LAT_CHAR = 'N';
 float LONGITUDE = 01131.0000;
 char LON_CHAR = 'E';
 int i = 1, j = 1;
 void intialize()
 {
  h = 00;
  m = 00;
  s = 00;
  MISSION_TIME = 0;
  ALT_SENSOR = 300;
  OUTSIDE_TEMP = 10;
  INSIDE_TEMP = 20;
  VOLTAGE = 12;
  FSW_STATE = 0;
  LATTITUDE = 4807.038;
  LONGITUDE = 01131.0000;
  i = 1; j = 1;
 } 
 void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
 }
 void loop()
 {
  Serial.print(TEAM_ID); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(MISSION_TIME); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(ALT_SENSOR); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(OUTSIDE_TEMP); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(INSIDE_TEMP); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(VOLTAGE); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(FSW_STATE); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(ROTOR_RATE); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(LATTITUDE); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(LAT_CHAR); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(LONGITUDE); Serial.print(',');
  Serial.print(LON_CHAR); 
  Serial.print('\n');
  delay(1000);
  MISSION_TIME += i;
  j += 1;
  if(s>59)
 {
  m=m+1;
  s += 1;
 }
  if(m>60)
 {
  h=h+1;
 }
  if(j==20)
 {
  FSW_STATE = 3;
 }
  if(j==30)
 {
  FSW_STATE = 4;
 }
  if(j==40)
{
 FSW_STATE = 5;
}
 if(j==50)
{
 FSW_STATE = 6;
}
 OUTSIDE_TEMP += 0.3;
 INSIDE_TEMP += 0.2;
 VOLTAGE -= 0.2;
 ALT_SENSOR -= 6;  
 s += 1;
 LATTITUDE += 0.3;
 LONGITUDE += 0.1;
 if(ALT_SENSOR == 0)
{
 intialize(); 
}
 loop;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to also include the arduino code? As it looks now, there is nothing seriously wrong with this python code. That would hint that maybe your assumption about the string returned from from the arduino is false.

Comment: The code has been included, please check and tell! :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are quite a few things that I'd change in your Arduino code, e.g. don't call `loop` (actually, you're not even calling it, you're just writing down the name) at the end of your loop, that would lead to infinite recursion. Also, your seconds, minutes, hours are going out of bounds: consider using the modulo operator.  Could you specify which Arduino board you're running this on? Also, I've added arduino tags to this question, because the problem is not with python.

Comment: Actually, are you *sure* that *that* code is uploaded to the Arduino? There is no way that `TEAM_ID` would be changed with the code you've shown and yet, that is what pyserial returns?

Comment: Actually, I was running this code on Arduino Uno, the code was uploaded as I can see the result in serial monitor of arduino IDE. And I need an infinite loop, I want to read the code continuously, till the python program is terminated. And yeah, TEAM_ID is not actually changing! The problem is pyserial is losing the data while reading! And thank you for your help sir!

Comment: Okay, I got the answer I think! At least, the code is returning the proper string now! Now, I don't know much of it but when I close the serial monitor and the arduino ide, the code is working properly. Now, can you please tell me, how this is working?

Comment: When you "close the serial monitor", you're not supposed to be receving anymore messages. So how do you know it is working properly now? Can you be a bit more specific (update the question if the answer's too long).

Comment: The pyserial program it also reads the data from arduino! So, when i close the serial monitor and run the program the results shows the data being received, now i don't know why and how is it happening?

Comment: Don't attempt to read from one opened serial port with several programs (in this case, the `Arduino IDE Serial Monitor` and `pyserial`, some operating systems might allow you to do that, but it is bad practice to try). As to *why* the data is being received when you close the serial monitor, that makes perfect sense, because your `pyserial` code acts then as a replacement for the `Arduino Serial Monitor` (that tool is merely there for convenience, it doesn't *grant* serial access for other programs). I'm inclined to close this question, because the problem isn't clearly described.

Comment: Okay! Got your point sir! Thank you for help! :)